# Highcharts sharing tooltip between linked series only

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm making a chart with an confidence interval bound like this: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange-line

It works great, but when there is more than one dataset (so, more than two series), the shared tooltips affect every series, when I only want it to mention the series (not the min and max values, and not the other line) the mouse is hovered over, as if `shared` were false.

Here's my relevant configuration:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true,
},

series: [{
    data: averages,
    zIndex: 1,
}, {
    data: ranges,
    type: 'arearange',
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    zIndex: 0,
}, {
    data: averages2,
    zIndex: 1,
}, {
    data: ranges2,
    type: 'arearange',
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    zIndex: 0,
}]
```

And here it is demonstrated in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ktd39x97/

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: A possible workaround could be checking if a series has `low` values (which the lines does not have, but the ranges do have). Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/ktd39x97/1/

Comment: It's not just the min and max values though, i also don't want it to show the other series. Could just hide it from the tooltip, but then it would highlight the points on the other series and I don't want that either.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what exactly you are after. From what I can read it seems you just want to show either averages or averages2 in your example, but nothing else? But that would be just setting `shared: false` which I don't think you want to do. Is this what you are after: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/ktd39x97/2/ ? If not, could you try to clarify what exactly should, and should not show when you hover over different places on in the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue *(basically wanting a combination of split and shared tooltips)*, incase anyone else runs into it:

In my case: I have 6 series, and 3 groups *(denoted by the same linkedTo value)*

```
const pointFormat = point => `<br/><span style="color:${point.color}">\u25CF</span> ${point.series.name}: <b>$${point.y.toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 0, minimumFractionDigits: 0 })}</b>`

tooltip: {
  formatter () {
    // split tooltips are an array of each point, with a first point for the header
    const tooltips = new Array(this.points.length + 1)
    // call the default tooltip header formatter

    tooltips[0] = this.point.series.chart.tooltip.tooltipFooterHeaderFormatter(this.points[0])

    // loop through the points, inserting a new shared tooltip for each new group
    const points = [...this.points]
    while (points.length > 0) {
      const point = points.shift()
      let pointTooltip = `<span style="font-size: 0.8em;">${point.series.userOptions.custom.fundName}</span>` + pointFormat(point)
      // some custom filter logic for finding the associated point from the other linked series
      // if you have more than 2 series per group, you'll need to extend this with an array
      const otherPointIndex = points.findIndex()
      if (otherPointIndex >= 0) {
        const otherPoint = points.splice(otherPointIndex, 1)[0]
        pointTooltip += pointFormat(otherPoint)
        tooltips[this.points.indexOf(otherPoint) + 1] = false // insert false so the tooltip for this point is ignored
      }
      // insert the shared tooltip at the original index
      tooltips[this.points.indexOf(point) + 1] = pointTooltip 
    }
    return tooltips
  },
  split: true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Highcharts doesn't support that kind of behavior of shared tooltip - there can be only one for all series.

**Workaround:**

This custom code can mimic the desired behavior using the standard no-shared tooltip:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function(e) {
      var point = this.point,
        series = point.series,
        chart = series.chart,
        correspondingSeries = series.linkedSeries[0] || series.linkedParent,
        linePoint,
        arearangePoint;

      // unselect previously selected point
      if (chart.extraHoveredPoint) {
        chart.extraHoveredPoint.setState('');
      }

      // find corresponding point
      if (correspondingSeries) {
        correspondingPoint = correspondingSeries.points[point.index];
        correspondingPoint.setState('hover');
        chart.extraHoveredPoint = correspondingPoint;
      }

      // identify type of points for formatting purposes
      if (point.low !== undefined) {
        arearangePoint = point;
        linePoint = correspondingPoint;
      } else {
        arearangePoint = correspondingPoint;
        linePoint = point;
      }

      return "Line: " + linePoint.y + "<br>" + "Arearange: " + arearangePoint.low + " - " + arearangePoint.high;

    }
  },
```

**API refences:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gq1d1aba/